# Schemes admitting a cover by isomorphic affine opens

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X$ be a Noetherian integral scheme. When does $X$ have a cover by affine open subschemes that are isomorphic as abstract schemes?

> Does there exist an example when we have a cover by $n$ affine opens
>   and a cover by some number of isomorphic affine opens but no cover by
>   $n$ isomorphic affine opens?

Arbitrary Noetherian integral schemes are pretty non-geometric (to my taste), so we might restrict to integral separated schemes of finite type over a field.

Some thoughts

- such a cover exists for affine schemes;
- such a cover exists for projective spaces;
- such a cover probably exists for smooth curves of genus 1 (I think the automorphism group should act transitively on the set of closed points);
- I think that a proper curve over a field with no automorphisms should not have this property (the isomorphism between the affines should extend to a morphism between the curves themselves, which has to be bijective because the image is closed, right?).

Comment: Meta discussion here:  https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4200/flood-of-new-users